# Incrementing a number with str_pad (PHP)

Tags: php, string, increment

I am creating an incrementing number starting with 1001. If the number goes 1001,1002,1003... when it reaches 10, will it be formatted like 1010 or will it be 10010? I need it to just go in order and be 1010 and when it reaches 100, 1100.

```
$prefix = "1"; // update the prefix here

    $number = 1;
    $number++;
    $unique = str_pad($number, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $unique = $prefix . $unique;

print_r($unique);
```

Comment: Why not just start from 1001? eg. what is your use case?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your count reaches 10, the number printed will be 1010.  As described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php), str_pad "Pads a string **to a certain length** with another string"  You can create a test with the following:

```
$prefix = "1"; // update the prefix here

$number = 1;

for ($number = 1; $number <= 100; $number++)
{    
  $unique = str_pad($number, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $unique = $prefix . $unique;    
  print($unique."\n");
 }
```

When your count reaches 100, the number printed will be 1100.

However, if you were to go up to 1000, 11000 would be printed - str_pad apparently will not *truncate* the string to match the specified size.

Answer (score 1):

It will be `1010`, but you can test this yourself easily:

```
$prefix = "1"; // update the prefix here

$number = 9;
$number++;
$unique = str_pad($number, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
$unique = $prefix . $unique;

print_r($unique);  // 1010
```

The second argument of [`str_pad`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) specifies padding. If padding is `3`, then `1` becomes `001`, `10` becomes `010`, `100` becomes `100`.

Answer (score 0):

With your code it will be `10010`.

It looks like you are making this more complicated than it needs to be. Why not just start with `$number = 1001` and increment it and then turn it into a string?

```
$number = 1001;
$number++;

$unique = strval($number);

print_r($unique);
```

Comment: This was actually the method I went with. I knew I was overcomplicating it, thanks.