# Multiple Records Submission at one time execution it should generate serial id's in HTML Form at a time of Insertion in Codeigniter2.2.6

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, codeigniter-2

Hi Guys Am facing the problem that is submitting the multiple records at a time but it should need to generate serial auto-generation number for every records
at a time of submission but i have storing only same id for every record and please refer the images for further information.thanks in advance.

code:

forms:

[image]

database:

[image]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your question?

Comment: take reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51871600/how-to-generate-a-next-series-number-and-compare-first-one-in-php/51873882#51873882. hope this will help you

Comment: Also while asking any question. Please mention your code.

Comment: hi @omkara how can get for every records ids based on database insertion for one receipt it okay but multiple records.its not working .thank you i will post my code.

Comment: Please @IshwaryaSwaminadhan mention your code or edit in your question to describe more.

Comment: hi @omkara see the above code i posted now.In form i skip some data .

Comment: if I am not wrong you want id like 47, 48 ,49 like that. use `$result['id']` instead of `$id=$result['group_cust']+1;`

Comment: but i tried the things same with that but still not working @omkara

Comment: take a look at once https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809811/incrementing-a-number-with-str-pad-php @IshwaryaSwaminadhan

Comment: thank you for your response @omkara i have done with another process

Comment: have fun and enjoy @IshwaryaSwaminadhan

Comment: ya sure @omkara some simple techinques in codeigniter and querys make huge things that's fine now for me buddy .